# PayPal Direct API alternative for non-US merchants

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have a PayPal merchant account registered in Germany and it seems that the direct API is not available in my case:

When trying to use the Direct API (DoDirectPayment) I get the error: 10565 Merchant country unsupported.

It there any other mechanism / API that I can use to allow my customers to pay with credit card without leaving my web site ?

Thanks !

UPDATE: 
I'm wondering though: Why was I able to create API credentials (username, password and signature) in my PayPal profile if I'm not able to use the API in Germany !? Really strange .. maybe someone could also clarify that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Paymill](https://www.paymill.com/) is such a service (and based in Germany).

Comment: Thanks Richie! I was hoping to find a way to use PayPal. But Paymill looks good - I'll have a closer look and get back with feedback in a few days.

Comment: Paymill seems perfect up to now! I'll go with it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The DoDirectPayment API is not avaiable in Germany at this time.  As to your other question, you were able to create the API credentials because these would be needed for other API calls to which you would have access to.  Such as Express Checkout, Reporting API, and etc.

Comment: Thanks Chad! Is there any other way to allow my customers to pay on my web site with PayPal in the background if I'm in Germany ? Or do I have to find another payment processor ?

Comment: On, your website - No.  They would have to be redirected over to PayPal's hosted pages to make the payment.